# Scrolling momentum on mobile devices

Tags: c#, mobile, physics, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to get a general smooth scrolling mechanism that I can implement in my mobile applications.

I want it to be generic enough so that it can port to any platform, but I am currently working in C# on the .net Compact Framework.

What I'm doing right now is:

- Create a Stopwatch object (in the panel's ctor)
- on mouse down start the Stopwatch and save the current mouse point `_lastMouse`
- on mouse move, stop the Stopwatch, and store `velocity = (_lastMouse - curMouse) / Stopwatch.TotalSeconds` then reset the Stopwatch and start it again

  - In most cases `Stopwatch.TotalSeconds` is between 0.02 and 0.03
- on mouse up, I pass the `velocity` value into a smooth scrolling function, and that function continues to scroll the panel until either the end is hit or the increasing friction causes the velocity to be == 0

My problem is in the final step.  The `velocity` values are generally int the 2,000-3,000 pixel range.  The velocity is in pixels per second, so this is to be expected.  I take the Stopwatch (which should be still running), stop it and I find the elapsed time from last mous move and multiply `velocity` by `Stopwatch.TotalSeconds`, get that distance and then reset and start the Stopwatch, then loop back and start all over again.

The expected result is that the elapsed time between refreshes multiplied by the velocity should give me the number of pixels (according to the last mouse move) that I should scroll.  My actual result is that sometimes the panel goes flying and sometimes it bearly moves! the gradual slowdown is fine, it's just the beginning velocity that is off

Is there a flaw in the logic?  Should I be doing something else?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: All newer frame-works have this built-in. At least state the version(s) you work with, this is a moving target. Better learn SilverLight.

Comment: Yeah, I guess all newer framewroks have built-in panel momentum helpers.  But I'm on the .net Compact Framewrok 3.5 and Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5 (not 6.5.3)

Comment: Look on CodePlex for fluent and mobile.

Comment: Do you know what the actual timing resolution and accuracy is on the platform?  Obviously if this is wonky then you will get funny results.  Also, how much variance is there in your scrolling?  Do you get the fast / slow scrolls even if you move at a constant pace?

Comment: The timing resolution is in ticks, so the millisecond should be pretty accurate.  The sparatic scrolling happens less frequently when moving at a constant pace.  If I do the flick at the end, that increases the irraticness (sometimes just stops, some times flies to the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there are three possible sources of inaccuracy here. Firstly, as "A.R." said, you'll have problems if the granularity of your timer isn't good enough. Have you checked `IsHighResolution` and `Frequency` to make *sure* it's OK?

Secondly, even if your timer is perfect, there may be some inaccuracy in your position measurements, and if you're taking two in very quick succession then it may hurt you. My guess is that this isn't a big deal, but e.g. if you're on a capacitive touchscreen then as the finger lifts off you may get variation in position as the contact area goes down.

Thirdly, the physical motion of the finger (or stylus or mouse or whatever you've got doing the actual input; I'm going to guess a finger) may not be all that well behaved. At the end of a gesture, it may change from being mostly horizontal to being mostly vertical.

All these problems would be substantially mitigated by using a longer sampling period and *maybe* (try it both ways) ignoring the very last sample or two. So, keep a little circular buffer of recent samples, and when you get the mouse-up look back (say) 100ms or thereabouts and use that to decide your velocity. Or, if you don't want to keep that much history, use a simple IIR filter: every time you get a sample, do something like

```
filtered_dt = filtered_dt + SMALL*(latest_dt-filtered_dt);
filtered_dx = filtered_dx + SMALL*(latest_dx-filtered_dx);
filtered_dy = filtered_dy + SMALL*(latest_dy-filtered_dy);
```

where SMALL should be, at a guess, somewhere around 0.2 or so; then use `filtered_dx/filtered_dt` and `filtered_dy/filtered_dt` as your velocity estimate. (I think this is better than calculating a velocity every time and filtering that, because e.g. the latter will still blow up if you ever get a spuriously small `dt`. If in doubt, try both ways.)

If you use the IIR approach, you may still want to make it ignore the very last sample if that turns out to be unreliable; if you remember the latest `dt`,`dx` and `dy` you can do that by undoing the last update: use `(filtered_dt-SMALL*latest_dt)/(1-SMALL)`, etc.

Here's an off-the-wall suggestion that may or may not work. You mentioned that you get more erratic results when there's a "flick" at the end of the gesture. Perhaps you can use that to your advantage: look at, say, how rapidly the estimated velocity is changing right at the end of the gesture, and if it's changing very rapidly then increase the velocity you use somewhat.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! I'll try them out on monday and see what happens. I'm beginning to think I need to incorporate fudge factors and not use pure physics. especially since this isn't a real time device

Comment: Ok, I've been playing with what you've posted and it has improved the scrolling.  It still isn't exactly what I want, but you've given me a good direction to go on :) Thanks!